# JAVA : formatting of text

Tags: java, formatting

I load a txt file as a collection of strings, then I save it in a Database HSQLDB. When i load from DB and print a `TextArea` The output type of text is this:

> Quando il flusso � maggiore nella narice di destra � la Nadi Pingala a
>   predominare. L'energia vitale � molto pi� attiva e di conseguenza
>   saremo pi� forti fisicamente, saremo pi� introversi e solari. Durante
>   il sonno tende a non.

How I can format it normally?

Comment: You should show us how you read from txt file, how your txt file is encoded and how you store and retrieve to/from DB

Comment: Is this being printed in Eclipse console? If so, have you set its char encoding to allow printing of your chars of interest? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030836/date-string-is-showing-question-marks

Comment: I load a txt file with those instructions in eclipse :                                                                                                       
 byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getPath()));
   t_inserimentoTItolo.setText(file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().indexOf(".")));
   return new String(encoded, "UTF-8");

Comment: And i load from DB with a classic ResultSet, the data are salved as VARCHAR

Answer (score 0):

Try to format your output text to UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1

Comment: I  used return new String(encoded, "UTF-8"); It does not solve the problem

Comment: Do you have the original text ?

Comment: Sure : Quando il flusso è maggiore nella narice di destra è la Nadi Pingala a predominare. L'energia vitale è molto più attiva e di conseguenza saremo più forti fisicamente, saremo più introversi e solari. Durante il sonno tende a non

Comment: I do this and is in the good format `new String(s.getBytes(), "UTF-8")`
Try to get all the string of the file before to `getBytes()`

Comment: I used return new String(encoded, "UTF-8");  encoded is array of bytes, my code is egual at yours

Comment: Try to get file content in a String and after set this in Bytes, the method `Files.readAllBytes()` shouldn't not be used I think

Answer (score 0):

The original text file must be in UTF-8 otherwise, it will be necessary to convert at the file reading time by:

new String (String_Readed_From_File.getBytes ("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");

If the encoding of the file is ISO-8859-1, otherwise adapt to file's encoding

Comment: I already do it :                                                                                    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getPath()));                    return new String(encoded, "UTF-8");

Comment: How about Database encoding setting ?

Comment: the data type in the DB is VARCHAR and then i load with a classic ResultSet.

Comment: I do not know for HSQLDB but the setting of the encoding is different from the data type. With PostgreSQL, for example, it is a parameter that is chosen at database creation time.

Comment: Displays the text after reading the file, then after reading the database. this will give you the real source of the problem. What is certain is that it's an encoding problem because it different from UTF-8 which is the encoding of Java.

Comment: I solved, it was the damn ANSI formatting of windows of the notepad that created problems. I rebuilt all the txt in UTF format 8, now it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you're saying, you're trying to read your text file as if it was encoded in UTF-8, but it is not. Therefore, you're failing the initial step of reading the file, and nothing you do afterwards can recover from this failure. It is useless to speak about what to do after reading the file.

We cannot guess what is the real encoding of your initial file. You would need to put this file somewhere for us to download it. All you've shown so far is that it is not in UTF-8 (because if it were, you would not have the problem described.)

You've said that you're using this code:

```
new String(encoded, "UTF-8");
```

Because "encoded" contains the bytes of your file, and your file is not in UTF-8, this instruction is wrong. You need to replace "UTF-8" with whatever is the true encoding of your file.

For instance it might be:

```
new String(encoded, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

**Another solution**, would be to not touch your Java code and leave it as-is, but make it correct by making its assumption that the file is in UTF-8, correct. For that you'd use a text editor out there like Notepad++, tell it to convert the file to UTF-8, and save.